# How to resolve ORA-00937: not a single-group group function when calculating percentage?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00937

I'm trying to get a percentage of the itemid that are available in a certain area.
Using my query, I get an error `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`

All the details:

I have these two tables:

```
ALLITEMS
---------------
ItemId  | Areas
---------------
1       | EAST
2       | EAST
3       | SOUTH
4       | WEST

CURRENTITEMS
---------------
ItemId
---------------
1
2
3
```

and want this result:

```
---------------
Areas| Percentage
---------------
EAST   | 50  --because ItemId 1 and 2 are in currentitems, so 2 items divided by the total 4 in allitems = .5
SOUTH  | 25   --because there is 1 item in currentitems table that are in area SOUTH (so 1/4=.25)
WEST   | 0  --because there are no items in currentitems that are in area WEST
```

The DDL:

```
drop table allitems;
drop table currentitems;

Create Table Allitems(ItemId Int,areas Varchar2(20));
Create Table Currentitems(ItemId Int);
Insert Into Allitems(Itemid,Areas) Values(1,'east');
Insert Into Allitems(ItemId,areas) Values(2,'east');
insert into allitems(ItemId,areas) values(3,'south');
insert into allitems(ItemId,areas) values(4,'east');

Insert Into Currentitems(ItemId) Values(1);
Insert Into Currentitems(ItemId) Values(2);
Insert Into Currentitems(ItemId) Values(3);
```

My Query:

```
Select  
areas,
(
Select 
Count(Currentitems.ItemId)*100 / (Select Count(ItemId) From allitems inner_allitems Where inner_allitems.areas = outer_allitems.areas )
From 
Allitems Inner_Allitems Left Join Currentitems On (Currentitems.Itemid = Inner_Allitems.Itemid) 
Where inner_allitems.areas = outer_allitems.areas
***group by inner_allitems.areas***
***it worked by adding the above group by***
) "Percentage Result"
From 
allitems outer_allitems
Group By 
areas
```

The error:

```
Error at Command Line:81 Column:41 (which is the part `(Select Count(ItemId) From allitems inner_allitems Where inner_allitems.areas = outer_allitems.areas )`)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

When I run the exact same query in SQL Server, it works fine.
How do I fix this in Oracle?

Comment: Thanks for the great responses. Different ways to do it! Thanks. I also found that by adding a group by (edited the question, look in My Query for "***") it is working too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Analytics are your friend:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       areas
      ,COUNT(currentitems.itemid)
       OVER (PARTITION BY areas) * 100
       / COUNT(*) OVER () Percentage
FROM allitems, currentitems
WHERE allitems.itemid = currentitems.itemid(+);
```

Comment: He mentions SQL Server and Oracle, perhaps the query must be portable, that is vendor agnostic.

Comment: portability shmortability :)

Answer (score 5):

Just for the heck of it, a way of doing it without analytics.

Jeffrey's solution needed a DISTINCT because of the duplication of `areas`.  The `allitems` table is actually an intersection table between `currentitems` and a putative `areas` table.  In the following query this is represented by the inline view `ai`. There is another inline view `tot` which gives us the total number number of records in `allitems`.  This count has to be included in the GROUP BY clause, as it is not an aggregating projector.

```
SQL> select ai.areas
  2         , (count(currentitems.itemid)/tot.cnt) * 100 as "%"
  3  from
  4      ( select count(*) as cnt from allitems ) tot
  5      , ( select distinct areas as areas from allitems ) ai
  6      , currentitems
  7      , allitems
  8  where allitems.areas = ai.areas
  9  and   allitems.itemid = currentitems.itemid(+)
 10  group by ai.areas, tot.cnt
 11  /

AREAS                         %
-------------------- ----------
east                         50
south                        25
west                          0

SQL>
```

I don't know whether this approach would perform better than Jeffrey's solution: it quite possibly will perform worse (the analytics query certainly has fewer consistent gets).  It is interesting simply because it highlights the issues more clearly.

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you for your input. I didn't get the time today, but I will be testing all the great answers tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick first pass:

```
select ai.areas,
       (sum(cnt) / max(tot)) * 100 "Percentage Result"
  from (select ai.itemid,
               ai.areas,
               count(ci.itemid) cnt,
               count(ai.areas) over () tot
          from allitems ai
               left outer join
               currentitems ci on (ai.itemid = ci.itemid)
        group by ai.itemid, ai.areas
       ) ai
group by ai.areas
```

Also, in your test data your itemid 4 needs to be changed to west.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification of your original query :

```
Select  
areas,
(
Select 
Count(*)
From 
Allitems Inner_Allitems Left Join Currentitems On (Currentitems.Itemid = Inner_Allitems.Itemid) 
Where inner_allitems.areas = outer_allitems.areas
) *100 / (Select Count(*) From allitems ) as percentage
From allitems outer_allitems
Group By areas
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Group 'By clause':

```sql
Select department_id, min(salary)
From employees
Group By department_id
Having min(salary) >
(
    Select min(salary)
    From employees
    Where department_id <> 50
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess even this helps:

```
SELECT
    distinct areas,
    NVL(x.count_item * 100,0) AS Percentage
FROM
    allitems a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ( COUNT(a.itemid) / (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    allitems
            ) ) AS count_item,
            areas AS avl_areas
        FROM
            allitems       a
            INNER JOIN currentitems   c ON a.itemid = c.itemid
        GROUP BY
            areas
    ) x ON x.avl_areas = a.areas
;
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I have found to work (though I think there's a bug here) is this:

```sql
-- Doesn't work (though it really should):
select 
  count(*),
  (select count(*) from dual)
from dual;

-- Works
select 
  count(*),
  (select count(*) from dual)
from dual
group by grouping sets (());
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=661d4e0f9818d18aa81804d20202c73d)