# Resolve ORA-00937: not a single-group group function on summing rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. In Table **A** I have:

```
  | A_ID | DESCRIP  | 
  +------+----------+
  |   1  |  Thing1  |
  |   2  |  Thing2  |
  |   3  |  Thing3  |
  | .... |   .....  |
```

And in Table **B** I have:

```
  | A_ID | Amount  | 
  +------+----------+
  |   1  |   5.5    |
  |   1  |   8.2    |
  |   1  |  10.5    |
  |   2  |   7.4    |
  |   2  |   1.7    |
  |   2  |  15.9    |
  |  ... |    ....  |
```

And I want to join the `SUM()` of the `AMOUNT` rows in Table **B** where it's `A_ID` matches the `A_ID` in Table **A**.

My SQL is currently like:

```
SELECT 
A.A_ID,
A.DESCRIP,
SUM(B.AMOUNT)
FROM 
A

LEFT JOIN
 B
ON
 A.A_ID = B.A_ID
ORDER BY ARINVT.ID
```

This issue has shown up many times on this site I've seen. I haven't been able to find one that quite helps my situation, but in the issue link below:

[This issue here probably helps my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150511/how-to-resolve-ora-00937-not-a-single-group-group-function-when-calculating-per)

I know I probably have to use analytics to resolve my problem. I have tried following some Youtube videos to do this but can't quite grasp. If someone could explain the accepted answer a bit more in the linked question it would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: Added the actual sql code being used. Was simplifying when I thought I would need analytics**

Current SQL:

```
SELECT 
ARINVT.ID,
ARINVT.CLASS,
ARINVT.ITEMNO,
ARINVT.DESCRIP,
ARINVT.ONHAND,
SUM(DAY_USE_TOTAL.TOT_MAT_QTY)

FROM 
IQMS.ARINVT ARINVT

LEFT JOIN
IQMS.DAY_USE_TOTAL DAY_USE_TOTAL
ON
ARINVT.ID = DAY_USE_TOTAL.ARINVT_ID

WHERE CLASS = 'PL'

GROUP BY ARINVT.ID,ARINVT.DESCRIP
```

The error I'm getting using `GROUP BY` is:
`ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: GROUP BY clause is missing, just add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use group by for non aggregated columns.

```
 SELECT ARINVT.ID,
     ARINVT.CLASS,
     ARINVT.ITEMNO,
     ARINVT.DESCRIP,
     ARINVT.ONHAND,
     SUM (DAY_USE_TOTAL.TOT_MAT_QTY)
FROM IQMS.ARINVT ARINVT
     LEFT JOIN IQMS.DAY_USE_TOTAL DAY_USE_TOTAL
        ON ARINVT.ID = DAY_USE_TOTAL.ARINVT_ID
   WHERE CLASS = 'PL'
GROUP BY ARINVT.ID,
         ARINVT.CLASS,
         ARINVT.ITEMNO,
         ARINVT.DESCRIP,
         ARINVT.ONHAND
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still having an error with my SQL. I'll upload what I'm using. at the moment. I had uploaded the other because I thought I would have to use analytics.

Comment: It worked thank you very much! I can see now I had to use every other column that wasn't summed.